# Property access time in JavaScript programs

Tags: javascript, v8

I want to compute the proportion of time spent on property accesses in JavaScript programs. I am aware of 
[code.com/svn/branches/bleeding_edge/tools/profviz/profviz.html](http://profile.com)
which is a cpu profiler.

[image]

But it is not clear what exactly does "execution" refer to since "ic cache" is shown seperately?

Does "execution" only include "Access time of properties"?

I am also interested in knowing the reasons behind the pause times shown in this plot. Are there any command line options that can help?